# nested ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have 2 variables promo_freq  and disc_freq . Based on the values of both these variables I want to create a 3rd variable promo_segmnt . However, the nested ifelse in R does not seen to work and the only value I am getting for my 3rd variable is "NA". As per my data, this must not be the output.
Please find the code mentioned below. 
Thanks in advance.

```
Promotion1$promo_segmnt <-ifelse(Promotion1$disc_freq == "1.Low_disc" & Promotion1$promo_freq == "1.Low_promo","1.Low",
ifelse(Promotion1$disc_freq == "2.Med_disc" & Promotion1$promo_freq == "3.High_promo","3.High",
ifelse(Promotion1$disc_freq == "3.High_disc" & Promotion1$promo_freq == "3.High_promo","3.High ","NA")))
```

Comment: can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal scenario works for me.

```
disc_freq <- c("1.Low_disc", "2.Med_disc", "3.High_disc", "4.na")
promo_freq <- c("1.Low_promo", "3.High_promo", "3.High_promo", "4.na")
Promotion1 <- data.frame(disc_freq, promo_freq)
```

**Promotion1**

```
disc_freq    promo_freq
<fctr>       <fctr> 
1.Low_disc  1.Low_promo         
2.Med_disc  3.High_promo            
3.High_disc 3.High_promo            
4.na    4.na


Promotion1$promo_segmnt <-
  ifelse(
  (Promotion1$disc_freq == "1.Low_disc") &
  (Promotion1$promo_freq == "1.Low_promo"),
  "1.Low",
  ifelse(
  (Promotion1$disc_freq == "2.Med_disc") &
  (Promotion1$promo_freq == "3.High_promo"),
  "3.High",
  ifelse(
  (Promotion1$disc_freq == "3.High_disc") &
  (Promotion1$promo_freq == "3.High_promo"),
  "3.High ",
  "NA"
  )
  )
  )

[1] "1.Low"   "3.High"  "3.High " "NA"
```

It is possible there are some extra spaces in your columns. you can remove it using stringr package.

```
library(stringr)

Promotion1 $disc_freq<- str_trim(Promotion1 $disc_freq, side = "both")
Promotion1 $promo_freq<- str_trim(Promotion1 $promo_freq, side = "both")
```

then try ifelse again.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! It worked. There was a problem with extra spaces. Removed it using the logic you gave. Now my program works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an alternative to using `if_else` then you could do this is using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse)) 

disc_freq <- c("1.Low_disc", "2.Med_disc", "3.High_disc", "4.na")
promo_freq <- c("1.Low_promo", "3.High_promo", "3.High_promo", "4.na")
Promotion1 <- data.frame(disc_freq, promo_freq)

mutate(Promotion1, promo_segmnt = case_when(
  disc_freq == "1.Low_disc" & promo_freq == "1.Low_promo" ~"1.Low",
  disc_freq == "2.Med_disc" & promo_freq == "3.High_promo" ~"3.High",
  disc_freq == "3.High_disc" & promo_freq == "3.High_promo" ~"3.High",
  TRUE ~"NA"))

#>     disc_freq   promo_freq promo_segmnt
#> 1  1.Low_disc  1.Low_promo        1.Low
#> 2  2.Med_disc 3.High_promo       3.High
#> 3 3.High_disc 3.High_promo       3.High
#> 4        4.na         4.na           NA
```